# React Native Navigation (6.3.2) - How to hide top statusBar completely in Android (see screenshot)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I am trying to build a new **react-native** application using **react-native-navigation**. earlier we have an application which is using v2.x of react-native-navigation and I am able to work with the navigation properly, where the notch and statusBar was properly getting handled by the navigation. But with version 6.x i am not able to hide the statusBar, or you can say draw behind the statusBar. See the screenshot below with old and new app.

here is the code snippet from the MainActivity (same in both the applications (old and new)).

```java
public class MainActivity extends NavigationActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            layoutParams.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES;
            getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

index.js

```js
/**
 * @format
 */

import App from './App';
```

App.js

```js
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';
import { WelcomePage } from './src/screens/welcome.page';
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';

Navigation.registerComponent(`Pages.WelcomePage`, () => WelcomePage);

StatusBar.setHidden(true);

Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(async () => {

  Navigation.setDefaultOptions({
    popGesture: false,
    topBar: {
      topMargin: 0,
      visible: false,
      drawBehind: true,
      animate: false,
      height: 0
    },
    layout: {
      orientation: 'portrait',
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      componentBackgroundColor: 'white',
      fitSystemWindows: true,
      topMargin: 0,
    },
    statusBar: {
      drawBehind: true,
      visible: false,
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      style: 'light'
    },
  });

  return Navigation.setRoot({
    root: {
      component: {
        name: 'Pages.WelcomePage',
      },
    },
  });
});
```

welcome.page.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StatusBar, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class WelcomePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <StatusBar hidden={true}/>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: '#556677', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1}}>
          <Text>Hello World</Text>
        </View>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export { WelcomePage };
```

## Device with Notch (New Application) RNN v6.x

[image: screen with notch]

## Device with Notch (Old Application) RNN v2.x

[image: screen with notch old app]

## Device without Notch (New Application) RNN v6.x

[image]

## Device without Notch (Old Application) RNN v6.x

[image]

please help me understand what is changed between these two versions in terms of layout handling and how I can achieve, what i was able to achieve with the older version of react-native-navigation.

Comment: it seems that the `Navigation.setDefaultOptions({statusBar: {visible: false});` is not working. i am required to set that option with every layout is pushed into the stack. I hope this is what I have understood.

Comment: did u find any solution? I'm facing the same issue!

Comment: don't remember now ... but i think i have used some workaround at that time.

Answer (score 0):

As per React Navigation v6 [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/status-bar) you can hide the status bar with FocusAwareStatusBar if you are using a tab navigator

```
function FocusAwareStatusBar(props) {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  return isFocused ? <StatusBar {...props} /> : null;
}
```